# Chakoteya.net links are broken

Tags: discussion, status-completed, hyperlinks

### **Update**

**Per Rand al'Thor♦'s answer below, the site manager for Chakoteya.net is apparently unwilling or unable to make changes at their end to resolve this problem.**

**That being the case, our options are now limited to trying to convince an SE Programmer to make the changes en-masse or making the changes ourselves.**

---

Sometime over the past few days, Chakoteya.net appear have changed the URLs of their episode transcripts, enforcing case and rendering the links broken.

http://www.chakoteya.net/nextgen/132.htm = No longer working
http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/132.htm = Working.

http://www.chakoteya.net/ds9/447.htm = No longer working
http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/447.htm = Working

http://www.chakoteya.net/doctorwho/32-12.htm = No Longer working
http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/32-12.htm = Working

http://www.chakoteya.net/voyager/718.htm = No Longer working
http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/718.htm = Working

http://www.chakoteya.net/startrek/16.htm = No Longer working
http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/16.htm = Working

---

A [quick search](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Achakoteya.net)  indicates that some 445+ answers possibly now have broken or invalid links, although the *actual number* is probably lower given that several will have already been fixed or will link to sources that are unaffected.

Obviously we could go through and just change all of those that are affected but this would engulf the front page. Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: mod 5 per day or 100 day... *{play trumpet whomp whomp}*

Comment: @Skooba - These aren't low value tag edits though, they're high value link edits.

Comment: I know, I am agreeing with you. Should have made more clear. Just found a bit of irony in it.

Comment: @Skooba - I'm just having a look now. It looks like more than half of them are mine so I can't claim to be unbiased in this

Comment: "Sometime over the past few days" - actually I think this has been the case for months, but [originally](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=26961468#26961468) I thought the problem was that the site was simply down, and didn't think to try changing the capitalisation in the URL.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - The other issue is that Chakoteya just isn't that reliable. It's frequently down.

Comment: @Valorum hey - when it's a free service by a volunteer - it's a little hard to be that upset about it. Maybe if people decided to make some donations they'd be able to use better hosting :)

Comment: @JonClements - I can't decide whether the fact that I've sent (tens of) thousands of people to the site counts as "doing my part" to help them.

Comment: @Valorum there is that :) Bit of a shame they state on the homepage they're adamant against doing ads as I'm sure they could have a little bit of a revenue stream if they did...

Comment: @JonClements - You aren't allowed to sell ad space if you host Star Trek stuff. Paramount (and their million lawyers) frown **very heavily** upon that.

Comment: @Valorum I was pondering if that were the case...

Comment: I've put this on the developer's schedule for next week. Whoever is the lucky winner of the ticket should be able to make the change in the database without bumping any posts. That said, it certainly doesn't hurt to make corrective edits if you happen to come across broken links.

Comment: And this is why your answers should not rely on third-party resources.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit - Well, it's certainly a good reason that link-only answers should get closed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have done a mass update to posts, post-history and comments for the following chakoteya urls:

- doctorwho → DoctorWho
- startrek → StarTrek
- nextgen → NextGen
- ds9 → DS9
- voyager → Voyager
- enterprise → Enterprise

If any others are affected, let me know by a comment here; I'll keep the script handy...

(I haven't run the script on "meta", as it would make this post **very** confusing!)

Comment: Cheers. Much obliged :-)

Comment: fun observation; "movies" is still `/movies/`, not `/Movies/` - gotta love consistency

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for raising this problem.

After seeing [Jon Clements's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92462/delta-flyer-transporter-capability/92465#comment337520_92465), **I've just sent an email to the Chakoteya site administrator** to ask them whether they could possibly fix the URLs so that e.g. http://www.chakoteya.net/doctorwho/30-15.htm redirects to http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/30-15.htm. That would be by far the simplest fix from our point of view - no editing needed here - and I'm hoping it'll also be not too hard for them to sort out this redirect.

**UPDATE**: I received a reply from the Chakoteya webmaster, who says the website itself hasn't changed (the folders for Doctor Who, DS9, etc. always had capitalised names, the only entirely lowercase folder being movies) and therefore they're not going to make any changes to the site, since they haven't done anything to create our situation.

Comment: SE was able to fix up all links from meta.so -> meta.se; is this a big enough problem for that to be an option?

Comment: @KutuluMike - It seems to be into the hundreds (plural). If we can avoid rectifying them by hand then we should certainly consider it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - How odd. The newer links are definitely different from the older ones.

Comment: Ho hum. Plan B is that we now need to change these links over. Would you mind coordinating that? I'm happy to do the majority of the legwork since the majority of the required edits appear be on my answers, but it's a non-trivial amount of work and I'd appreciate not being shouted at for spamming.

Comment: @Randal'Thor : Is it impossible to have SE devs write a script that simply makes the appropriate substitutions across the SFF:SE SQL database?

Comment: @Valorum : See above to Rand.

Comment: @Praxis It's theoretically possible, but I imagine it'll be quite hard to talk them into doing it, since they must have lots of other stuff on their to-do lists which is of network-wide importance. Also, 'messing up the front page' is a pretty inconceivable problem to SO-based people. I can ask if you want, but don't hold out too much hope.

Comment: @Valorum : I see now your update to the post above about such an en-masse change being unlikely.  But why?  From a database point of view, it's pretty simple.  Is it that they don't want to start a precedent?

Comment: @Randal'Thor : Not only theoretically possible, it's absolutely possible and very simple.

Comment: @Valorum If we're going to have an edit flood anyway, some of the retagging squad might be interested in joining in with their own edits, since the front page will be messed up anyway. E.g. adding the [tag:star-trek] tag to all ST questions that don't have it, since a ton of ST posts will be bumped anyway.

Comment: @Randal'Thor : The posts are database entries.  Making the substitution across the database would not affect front pages whatsoever.  Editing at the database-level would not push posts to the top.

Comment: @praxis - When we've asked for these sorts of changes in the past, the answer has been no.

Comment: @Valorum : Darn.  We should still ask though.

Comment: @praxis - Yes, we should. And when the answer comes back, then we can decide what to do.

Comment: @Praxis I've just enquired into the possibility via mod channels. Fingers crossed!

Comment: @Randal'Thor : Great!  I'm hopeful.

Comment: @praxis - Rule of Acquisition #108.

Comment: This has nothing to do with browsers, and everything to do with the web server. He may have not actively changed settings, but the proper fix is to update his server settings.

Comment: Yes, @phantom42 is correct. The folders didn't change, but his web server is now enforcing case sensitivity. He changed something in his configuration, and it could have happened without him knowing during an update or other normal maintenance event.

Comment: @Praxis And I got a response from on high! See the latest comment on the question :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor : Yay!  You're a star.  :-D

Comment: @Valorum : Hope prevails.  ;-)

Comment: Someone should send them another email. This is generally a single line or single checkbox fix, and it's broken every link and bookmark and feed to their site. It's not just us that's affected.  He should at least be encouraged to contact web host support, if he's unsure, to see why his server is suddenly enforcing URL case sensitivity.

Comment: @CreationEdge already been done and assistance in that regard has been effectively rejected. And they're a "she" not a "he" :)

Comment: @JonClements And usually I say "they" or "she" and when I read it I was too lazy to fix it because text editing on mobile is dumb. So, of course this is the time that pronouns come and get me. Thanks, though!

Comment: I'd guess they switched from a windows server (typically case-insensitive) to a linux server (typcially case-sensitive).

Comment: @Randal'Thor if you can send them link to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814419/how-do-i-make-urls-case-insensitive-in-linux-server) it might solve the issue for the thousands of broken links outside of SE.